# ordenar un objeto arrays cuando hay iguales un atributo

Tags: javascript-objeto, javascript-metodo

No sé cómo comparar dos elementos del array de objetos para ordenarlo. Cuando pongo que son iguales no me compara el objeto, me aparece como indefinido.

```js
let compras = [
    {
        nombre: "azucar",
        precio: 12.9
    },
    {
        nombre: "poroto",
        precio: 1.8
    },
    {
        nombre: "arroz",
        precio: 12.9
    },
    {
        nombre: "lenteja",
        precio: 0.7
    }
]

function SortArray(x, y){
    if (x.precio < y.precio) {
        return 1;
    }else if (x.precio > y.precio) {
        return -1;
    }else{
        if (x.nombre < y.nombre) {
            return 1;
        }else if (x.nombre > y.nombre) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
var s = compras.sort(SortArray);
console.log(s)
```

**cuando el precio sea igual lo ordene por su nombre los objetos iguales?**

quisiera que el resultado fuera en ese orden:

```
{nombre: "arroz", precio: 12.9}
{nombre: "azucar", precio: 12.9}
{nombre: "poroto", precio: 1.8}
{nombre: "lenteja", precio: 0.7}
```

comparar el precio y si es igual comparar los iguales con el atributo nombre

Comment: Buenas, podrías subir un ejemplo de como querrías que sea el resultado?. Es más sencillo así ayudarte, te sugiero leer el apartado "Como preguntar?". Gracias

Comment: {"arroz", 12.9}, {"azucar", 12.9}, {"poroto", 1.8}, {"lenteja", 0.7}

Comment: Te recomiendo leer el [tour] y [ask] para conocer mejor cómo funciona SOes

Answer (score 0):

Lo tienes casi todo bien, no veo ese `undefined` del que hablas. El problema es a la hora de ordenar alfabéticamente por nombre, que lo haces al revés (devuelves -1 cuando debería ser 1 y viceversa).

Puesto que `Array.sort` ordena de menor a mayor (orden ascendente), se me ocurre que puedes refactorizar un poco el código para simplificarlo: He creado una función que compara dos elementos y para invertir el orden sólo hemos de cambiar el orden de los parámetros que le pasamos: el precio lo comparamos usando `(y, x)` y el nombre con `(x, y)`:

```js
let compras = [
    {
        nombre: "azucar",
        precio: 12.9
    },
    {
        nombre: "poroto",
        precio: 1.8
    },
    {
        nombre: "arroz",
        precio: 12.9
    },
    {
        nombre: "lenteja",
        precio: 0.7
    }
];

function compareValues(a,b) {
  if (a < b) {
    return -1;
  }
  if ( a > b) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

function SortArray(x, y) {
  const preciosComparados = compareValues(y.precio, x.precio);
  if (preciosComparados === 0) {
    return compareValues(x.nombre, y.nombre);
  }
  return preciosComparados;
}
 
var s = compras.sort(SortArray);
console.log(s)
```

Comment: gracias si me sirvio